# Finding x with a Python-script in a difficult equation where x is only variable

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, equation

I have some difficult equations where x is the only variable. For example this one:

**atan(12/x)-atan(SQRT(7x)/31)=atan((3x+942+sqrt(2x^2+2))/(4+sqrt(5+x^2)))**

In software like WolframAlpha I can paste it in at it will find the x for me easily.

[image: X found to be around 0.00523 by Wolfram Alpha]

The only idea I have now is to do some sort of brute force on each side with small iterations until Left side = Right side. I have no idea how to elegantly solve this equation using python.

Does anyone where I should start?

(Disclaimer: I have written some basic python scripts and studied some math, but my math skills and python skills are probably in the bottom 1% in the Stack Overflow-community.)

Best regards,

Comment: You could set the two equations equal to each other and use the secant method. I'd suggest posting this question in the [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: It seems like your question is basically "how do I use python to solve equations?" which is too broad for Stack Overflow. It's also, incidentally, something you can [literally type into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+I+use+python+to+solve+equations%3F) and get some useful pointers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the direction of the secant method, looks relevant!

Comment: Apologise if it was too basic Karl. To clarify: I have solved equations on Python before, but not something nearly as complex as this that can't be reduced to simpler terms. I was wondering how you would go about solving this - and the secant method seems smart.

Comment: You can try using `sympy` if you want symbolic solutions and also you can take a look at `scipy.optimize.fsolve`or `scipy.optimize.newton`. The latter also implements the secant method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult equation, both symbolically and numerically. Mathematica has very advanced algorithms. `nsolve` from sympy does not find the root without help, but you can do the following:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
e0 = atan(12/x)-atan(sqrt(7*x)/31)-atan((3*x+942+sqrt(2*x**2+2))/(4+sqrt(5+x**2)))
nsolve(e0,x,0)
# gives ZeroDivisionError
nsolve(e0,x,0.001)
# gives 0.00523293635181032 - 1.6278511388129e-27*I
nsolve(e0,x,0.005)
# gives 0.00523293635181032
```

So you have to guess the range of the zero rather closely.

To make the search for the root easier, you can get rid of `atan` by taking the `tan` of both sides and use `tan(a-b) = (tan(a) - tan(b)) / (1 + tan(a)tan(b))` :

```
t1 = 12 / x
t2 = sqrt(7*x) / 31
t3 = (3*x+942+sqrt(2*x**2+2)) / (4+sqrt(5+x**2))
# atan(t1) - atan(t2) = atan(t3) is equivalent to e1 = 0:
# (note: tan(atan(t1) - atan(t2)) = (t1-t2)/(1+t1*t2) )
e1 = simplify((t1-t2)/(1+t1*t2) - t3)
# gives (sqrt(x)*(31*sqrt(x) + 12*sqrt(7))*(-3*x - sqrt(2*x**2 + 2) - 942) + ...)/(sqrt(x)*...)
```

Now we have to give `nsolve` one more hint to make the root search easier, namely to take only the numerator of the expression:

```
e1_num = e1.as_numer_denom()[0]
# gives (sqrt(x)*(31*sqrt(x) + 12*sqrt(7))*(-3*x - sqrt(2*x**2 + 2) - 942) + (-sqrt(7)*x**(3/2) + 372)*(sqrt(x**2 + 5) + 4)
nsolve(e1_num,x,0)
# gives 0.00523293635181032
```